# White Page error in magento not able to login

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I am freshly installed the magento.. when i am trying to login to the admin it is showing the blank page.. my site url is:http://magento.dotmappers.in i am usin ver 1.8.0

Comment: your site is taking too long to load, there can be some issue with the code, check var/log/system.log or var/log/exception.log to check what exactly the issue is

Answer (score 0):

It probably has something to do with cookies.

Go to `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php` and find following lines and comment out last three lines and try again:

```
$this->getCookie()->getLifetime(), 
$this->getCookie()->getPath() 
// $this->getCookie()->getDomain(), 
// $this->getCookie()->isSecure(), 
// $this->getCookie()->getHttponly()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not installed sample data, so pls install sample data from below link

[[http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/installing-sample-data-archive-for-magento-ce][1]](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/installing-sample-data-archive-for-magento-ce%5d%5b1%5d)

Answer (score 0):

your site is taking too long to load, there is some issue with the code.

The site can't call the file

```
`magento.dotmappers.in/js/prototype/prototype.js`
```

This file is not accessible in browser also, please check if it exits.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed magento sample data ?

Comment: you can access your admin site using this url. http://magento.dotmappers.in/admin